# How can i target a specific item from a list of array on Hover in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of movies that I got from an API and I displayed them using the Map method, I'm trying to work on an option that when I hover on one of the cards I want to show the trailer of that specific movie in the place of the image. The problem that I face is when I hover, the video trailer is playing on all the cards, I would like to know how I can play that video on hover for a specific card.

**My card component**

```
const MovieCard = ({moviesList}) => {
    const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
    const trailer =
    "https://player.vimeo.com/external/371433846.sd.mp4?s=236da2f3c0fd273d2c6d9a064f3ae35579b2bbdf&profile_id=139&oauth2_token_id=57447761";
    return (
       moviesList.map((singleMovie)=> {
           const {id , title, poster_path, overview} = singleMovie;
            return (
               <article key={id} className="card"
                onMouseEnter= {()=> setIsHover(true)}
                onMouseLeave={()=> setIsHover(false)}>
                   <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title} className="image"/>
                   {isHover && <video src={trailer} autoPlay={true} loop></video>}
                   <div className="body-card">
                   <h1>{title}</h1>
                   <p>{`${overview.substring(0,200)}...`}</p>
                   </div>
                   
               </article>
            )
       })
          
    )
}
```

export default MovieCard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `boolean` flag you can store the `id` and frankly, this functionality should go in the individual `Card` and you should render that `Card` in the loop.

Here's how you can do in the same implementation.

```js
const MovieCard = ({moviesList}) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
    const trailer =
    "https://player.vimeo.com/external/371433846.sd.mp4?s=236da2f3c0fd273d2c6d9a064f3ae35579b2bbdf&profile_id=139&oauth2_token_id=57447761";
    return (
       moviesList.map((singleMovie)=> {
           const {id , title, poster_path, overview} = singleMovie;
            return (
               <article key={id} className="card"
                onMouseEnter= {()=> setSelected(id)}
                onMouseLeave={()=> setSelected(null)}>
                   <img src={`${ImgPath}` + poster_path} alt={title} className="image"/>
                   {selected === id && <video src={trailer} autoPlay={true} loop></video>}
                   <div className="body-card">
                   <h1>{title}</h1>
                   <p>{`${overview.substring(0,200)}...`}</p>
                   </div>
                   
               </article>
            )
       })
          
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your movieCard component not actually a movieCard component. Because you are taking the list of movie as a props so this is a movieCardList component. Instead doing that you can create a movieCard component that renders one movieCard element and inside of that component you can show the trail video in separatly.

```
    const movieCard =({movie} ) ={
  const handleTrailerShow = () =>{} 
return <div onSomeEvent={handleTrailerShow} >
  .... 
 </div>
}
```

And in your main component

```
const movieCardList =({movieList} ) ={
    return movieList.map(movie=>
<MovieCard movie={movie} />

 }
```