# How to handle multiple Material UI Slide Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI `Slide`. Here Is my code. What I want to do is, individual `slide` will appear when I hover over a certain card. but with this code, both `slide` is appearing when hovering any one of the cards.

handler:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
const handleSlide = () => {
      setChecked(!checked);
  };
```

jsx:

```
<Card onMouseEnter={handleSlide} onMouseLeave={handleSlide} sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
  <CardContent>
    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
      Card 1
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
      Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
      species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
    </Typography>
  </CardContent>
  <Slide direction="up" in={checked}>
    <CardActions>
      <Button size="small">Button 1</Button>
      <Button size="small">Button 2</Button>
    </CardActions>
  </Slide>
</Card>

<Card onMouseEnter={handleSlide} onMouseLeave={handleSlide} sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
  <CardContent>
    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
      Card 2
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
      Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
      species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
    </Typography>
  </CardContent>
  <Slide direction="up" in={checked}>
    <CardActions>
      <Button size="small">Button 1</Button>
      <Button size="small">Button 2</Button>
    </CardActions>
  </Slide>
</Card>
```

What should I do to achieve what is want.

Comment: You could store your text / images in an array, than loop through it and implement one of these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328510/how-can-i-target-a-specific-item-from-a-list-of-array-on-hover-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding after reading your question, in your code both `card`s are using the same state as a result when you hover any of them affect both. To make each card behave uniquely you have to make sure each component uses its own state, not common state. For this, my suggestion is to make a new `Card` component with `State` and `Handler` methods. then render it where the `cards` are rendered right now. like bellow.

New card component:

```
const CardComponent = (props) => {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
    const handleSlide = () => {
        setChecked(!checked);
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Card onMouseEnter={handleSlide} onMouseLeave={handleSlide} sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                        {props.title}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                        Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
                        species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <Slide direction="up" in={checked}>
                    <CardActions>
                        <Button size="small">Button 1</Button>
                        <Button size="small">Button 2</Button>
                    </CardActions>
                </Slide>
            </Card>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Then replace your card with this new card component and pass properties to each card as `props`.

```
<CardComponent title={'Card 1'} />
<CardComponent title={'Card 2'} />
```

I hope this will solve your issue.